# Does thermal energy include the kinetic energy of the electrons?

Tags: thermodynamics

Or is the kinetic energy of the electrons not counted towards the thermal energy? (In other words only the energy of the lattice structure is counted)

Comment: connected http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/what-are-the-six-degrees-of-freedom-of-the-atoms-in-a-solid . The potential and kinetic energy of electrons bound in the potential around the nucleus of the atoms composing the material is part of the internal energy of the system ( which ultimately includes the E=mc**2 of the masses)

Comment: @annav So the kinetic energy of the electrons *is* included?

Comment: No. It is within the packaged atoms, part of the internal energy . The electrons are in quantized non changeable energy levels about the nucleus. The atoms as a whole have vibrational degrees of freedom in the lattice. As far as the definition of heat is concerned, which is a thermodynamic concept, but has been described by a statistical mechanics formulation, the atoms are non divisible, what their name says. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the question is: is the bulk motion of electrons taken into account in the thermal energy?

Thermal energy is energy that is distributed among the degrees of freedom of your system. 
"If a system contains N molecules, each with f degrees of freedom, and there are no other (non quadratic) temperature-dependent forms of energy, then its total thermal energy is":
$$U_{thermal}=Nf\frac{1}{2}kT$$
This is temperature-dependent energy. Now lets look at the degrees of freedom among which it could be distributed (depending which modes are available).. it includes $\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2$, $\frac{1}{2}mv_y^2$,...,$\frac{1}{2}\omega_x^2$ etc.

Now the equipartition theorem states: "At temperature T, the average energy of any quadratic degree of freedom is" $$\frac{1}{2}kT$$
This kinetic energy due to the temperature of a substance is distributed equally among the available degrees of freedom. 
I think the kinetic energy you are referring to is bulk motion, which has nothing to do with the equilibrium statistics of a system.

The subtle aspect here is that a system can be in thermodynamic equilibrium with its constituents obeying bolztmann statistics while the system as a whole may be moving. Try this for a thought experiment; imagine moving the "microcanonical ensemble" at a constant velocity. Are the bolztmann statistics affected if you are in the reference frame of the moving "box of particles"?

Ref: Schroeder page 15 <3.