# What is the difference between a rigid diatomic molecule and non-rigid diatomic molecule?

Tags: thermodynamics, vibrations, molecules

I started a mock paper for one of my entrance exams with this fairly easy question. I rearranged the equation and got 5/2, knowing that a diatomic molecule has a Cv of 5/2, i concluded that the answer must be either A or C, but I do not know the difference between rigid diatomic and non rigid diatomic, can someone explain the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At sufficiently high temperature, a diatomic molecule may have a thermodynamic degree of freedom that corresponds to bond length oscillation.   That
would change the '5/2' to '6/2'.

Comment: The vibratory behavior adds *two* quadratic terms to the Hamiltonian, so the change is from 5/2 to 7/2. This is a good reason to be careful how you talk about equipartition: it's very easy to be sloppy about about [the meaning of 'degree of freedom' ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/317605/520) and fool yourself.

Comment: Just to confirm , when we increase the energy of the system it is able to get two more degrees of freedom , thereby changing from rigid diatomic (5/2) to non rigid diatomic (7/2) ... That made sense thanks, both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Rigid diatomic molecule has $C_v = 5/2$ and non rigid has $C_v = 7/2$. From this we can fairly distinguish between both.
Examples of rigid molecules include $\mathrm{Cl_2}, \mathrm{Br_2}, \mathrm{N_2}, \mathrm{O_2}$ and so on.
An example of a non-rigid molecule is $\mathrm{CO}$.

Comment: These might be good examples, but they don't explain *why* some are rigid while others are not.