# What is the formal definition of Degree of Freedom?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

Is the degree of freedom defined in [**classical mechanics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(mechanics)) same as the degree of freedom in [**thermodynamics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry))?
If not what is the formal definition of degree of freedom in **thermodynamics**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the degree of freedom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391162/)

Comment: i saw that answer but can you atleast answer the second question?

Comment: To reopen this post (v3) consider to only ask one subquestion per post.

Comment: I feel like all of your questions are answered in the link. Hence why I put it as possible duplicate. If others don't agree then it won't be marked as a duplicate and others can answer the question if they choose to do so. I'm not going to add an answer that repeats what I put a link for.

Comment: can you just say whether the two degree of freedom in thermodynamics same as that of classical mechanics?