# What is degree of freedom in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

I have read a lit bit of degree of freedom in classical mechanics and hope to understand as if the number of variable used to describe a system in the configuration space. But in thermodynamics I read something vibrational degree of freedom , rotational degree of freedom .What is the definition of **vibrational and rotational degree of freedom**? Are this same as degree of freedom in classical mechanics If how to prove the equivalence?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317600/ and links therein.

Comment: Hi Bijayan Ray. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.